# Java Spring can not make GetRequest

Tags: java, spring

I have just started a Spring tutorial. I do everything the same as the lecturer, but if I make a getRequest nothing changes. I also do not have any grey globe icons next to the @RequestMapping and @GetMapping annotations [ss of grey globe icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAxvt.png). Would be happy to have any suggestions. Here is the erorr I get when I call the controller endpoint [error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPINI.png)

```
package Controller;

import model.Il;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/iller")
public class ILController {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Il>> getIller(){

        Il il1 = new Il("34", "Istanbul");
        Il il2 = new Il("06", "Ankara");
        List<Il> iller = Arrays.asList(il1, il2);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(iller, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Il class:

```
package model;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Il {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Il(){
        this.id = "defaultId";
        this.name = "defaultName";
    }

    public Il(String id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: How you are calling this controller endpoint. Attach screenshot in question itself. Are you getting any error?

Comment: I am simply calling it with http://localhost:8080/iller and the error I get is not found error, 404.

Comment: I attached the screenshot to the end of the question

Comment: When you start the application, do you see any log saying that your endpoint "killer" is successfully mapped? The Whitelabel error means that you are trying to hit some wrong endpoint or your endpoint is not successfully mapped.

Comment: No, I do not get it.

Comment: Did you add your controller package to the spring component scan configuration?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please check the pom also:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

application.yml

```
server:
   port: 9090
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Regarding the Glob Icon feature, I think that feature is only available in the IntelliJ Enterprise version.

By clicking that grey globe icon it gives 3 options -

1. Go to declaration or usage
2. Generate request in HTTP Client
3. Show all endpoints of module

Comment: To be honest, the grey globe icon is not important to me, but my program does not work and I thought maybe the absence of the grey globe icon is an indicator of something wrong.

Comment: Oh okay, actually I tried the same code you posted, and it's working perfectly so I thought you are looking for the globe icon only

Comment: I've added the screenshot of your code and the pom please check once if it helps

Comment: I have realized I do not have any application.yml file, where you have it.

Comment: after adding the `application.yml` is it working?

Answer (score 0):

I built your example from scratch with Intellij. Could you try re-editing your code as in the screenshot? If you need help with Spring, please write.

[image]

Comment: I tried it, but it does not change. Postman still can not send request to localhost and no changes still 404 on localhost.

Comment: Hi ege126, you can create a github/gitlab public repo and push all code in this repo then share it with us. we can find errors. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to fill the annotation @GetMapping with a path that defines your GET method.
For example, try something like this:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/GetIller")

public ResponseEntity<List<Il>> getIller(){

    Il il1 = new Il("34", "Istanbul");
    Il il2 = new Il("06", "Ankara");
    List<Il> iller = Arrays.asList(il1, il2);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(iller, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Same for other HTTP methods (POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE ...)